# Is $g(t)=\int_{E} f(x) \cos tx \, dx$ continuously differentiable? Have compact support?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded Lebesgue measurable function. Define $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$g(t) = \int_{E} f(x) \cos tx \, dx.$$

Is $g$ continuously differentiable? Does $g$ have compact support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$ f(x)\cos (tx) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n} f(x) \, t^{2n}. $$

Since $E$ is bounded, $\left|x\right| \leq M$ for some $M > 0$. This gives

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{E} \frac{\left|x\right|^{2n}}{(2n)!} \left|f(x)\right| \, dx
\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{M^{2n}}{(2n)!} \int_{E} \left|f(x)\right| \, dx < \infty.$$

Thus if we put

$$ a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \int_{E} x^{2n} f(x) \, dx, $$

it follows from the Fubini's theorem that

$$ g(t) = \int_{E} f(x)\cos (tx) \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t^{2n}. $$

In particular, $g(t)$ is analytic on $\Bbb{R}$. Indeed, this follows from the observation that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n} \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{M^{2n}}{(2n)!} \int_{E} \left|f\right| \right)^{1/n} = 0.$$

Since $g(t)$ is analytic, $g(t)$ cannot vanish identically on any open set unless $a_n = 0$ for all $n$, or equivalently, every $n$-th moment of $f$ vanishes for even $n$. Therefore the support of $g$ is either $\varnothing$ or $\Bbb{R}$.

Finally, by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, it follows that $g(t) \to 0$ as $|t| \to \infty$.